# Angular project not able to add with api folder in GIT command line

Tags: java, angularjs, git, github

I am not able to see angularclient folder in git status
i am not sure what the issue is
the api is added and visable but angularclient never shows up in git status
 of main folder

[Main folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TWwV7.png)

[image]

[api](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gSgSd.png)

[image]

[gitignore file in main folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/06PgQ.png)

[image]

[angularclient](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J5rkE.png)

[image]

Comment: So, if you make a file change under angularclient/, `git status` won't report those changes?

Comment: yes
when i change any thing, nothing shows up in git status